# How to disable parent window while pop up component appears in angular2?

Tags: angular, popupwindow

I created popup component referring this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-opd-popup. I want to disable parent window while popup window appears,How could it possible ?

Comment: You need to put a div for overlay like you need like this

Answer (score 0):

Now you can PLACE YOUR POPUP HERE

Anf give the position fixed for overlay

```
  .overlay{
    Position:fixed;
    Width:100;
    Height:100;
    Top:0
    Left:0
    Top:0
    Bottom:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are others solutions with CSS and code only, I can guide you toward the angular material components.
This is something you should look into :

https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav